# How to reduce gap between axis and axis's ticker in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to reduce the distance in below graph with `hjust` and `vjust` arguments in `axis.text.x` of `theme` function but still I couldn't manage to create a nice output.

```
d %>%
  filter(ISO3 == "SLE") %>%
  select(starts_with("DQQ"), YEAR_WAVE) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("DQQ"), names_to = "DQQ", values_to = "Value") %>%
  filter(Value == 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(DQQ, fill = as.factor(YEAR_WAVE))) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  labs(fill = "Year") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 200)) +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(0, .5, 0, 0), "cm"),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "cm"),
    #aspect.ratio = 0.5,
    legend.position = c(0.75, .95),
    legend.justification = c("right", "top"),
    legend.box.just = "right",
    legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6),
    axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", color="#993333", size = 12, angle=90, hjust = 0.1, vjust = 0.5)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0, 0, 200))` or `scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0, 200))`. You specified an expansion of 200 at both the lower and the upper end.

Comment: Thanks @stefan, that works. Could you please help me on how to sort my x axis tickers from DQQ1 to DQQ29.

Comment: Try with adding `mutate(DQQ = reorder(DQQ, str_rank(DQQ, numeric = TRUE)))` after the pivot_longer. That should convert to factor with the desired order, where str_rank with numeric = TRUE will treat the digits as numerics when sorting.

Comment: Again thanks @stefan, but that did not work. I use `mutate(DQQ = reorder(DQQ, stringr::str_order(DQQ, numeric = TRUE)))`. `str_rank` not recognized.